# Marketing Cloud SFTP File Deletion

Tags: marketing-cloud, sftp

**Scenario:**
PDFs are uploaded via SFTP to MC to be used at will. Meaning they should not be deleted. However, MC warns deletion of files uploaded via SFTP after 21 days.

**Question:**
Base my understand - of the Salesforce help documentation, creating an automation that updates a DE with the PDF links, will this prevent them from being deleted. Do I understand this correct?

See Salesforce help document below:

[image]

Comment: You do not, what is the use case to store a file for more then 21 days on SFMC FTP? You could evalute uploading files to content builder

Comment: The import from enhanced FTP to data extensions is not related to PDF files. It is more about importing data from uploaded CSV files into data extensions.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to salesforce support team on modifying the file retention date setting in sftp ?